# Linearizing equations of motion around a circular orbit

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations, physics, mathematical-physics, linearization

I am given the equations of motion:
$$\dot{r} = f(r)p_r,$$
$$\dot{p_r} = -\frac{V'(r)}{2f(r)}-\frac{f'(r){p_r}^2}{2}+\frac{V(r)-E^2}{2f^2(r)}f'(r)$$
Along with the conditions that $$E^2-V(r_0)=V'(r_0)=0$$

I need to linearize the equations of motion around a circular orbit at $r=r_0$ so that I get:
$$\delta\dot{r}=\delta p_r,$$
$$\delta \dot{p_r}=-\frac{V''(r_0)\delta r}{2f(r_0)}$$

How to get the solution by using the concept of linearization?

**Edit**

I tried to calculate the Jacobian matrix using Mathematica:

```
jacobianMatrix = 
 Grad[{f[r] p[r], -V'[r]/(2 f[r]) - (f'[r] p[r]^2)/
        2 + (V[r] - En^2)/(2 f[r]^2) f'[r]}, {r, p[r]}] /. r -> r0 /. 
    En^2 -> V[r0] /. V'[r0] -> 0 // MatrixForm
```

which gives me the output:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p_{r_0} f'({r_0}) & f({r_0}) \\
 -\frac{1}{2} p_{r_0}^2 f''({r_0})-\frac{V''({r_0})}{2 f({r_0})} & -p_{r_0} f'({r_0}) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

where I am getting the $-\frac{V''(r_0)}{2f(r_0)}$ term along with extra terms, I am not sure why the other terms vanish.

Source: [Probing phase structure of black holes with Lyapunov exponents](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/JHEP08(2022)153)
(page 13)

Comment: What do you know about linearization, what is your approach to it? It can be systematic using partial derivatives or procedural/manual by inserting linear Taylor polynomials, or dual numbers if this is more approachable to you.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I tried doing it using partial derivatives but got stuck.

Comment: Then please document how and where you got stuck. Add this to the question text.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I have shown the details in the edit.

Comment: The radial impulse component is zero, for a circular orbit the radius does not change. This removes some terms.

Comment: But in the reference paper, they even neglect the single `f(r0)` term somehow.

Comment: Which is strange, as it is kept in the second equation. It could be a transmission error from manuscript to electronic article, check the use that is made of the linearization, there could be follow-up errors. The frequency of the perturbation term should be $\sqrt{V''(r_0)/2}$.

Comment: In the stability matrix, they have used $f(r_0)$, so $p_{r_0}$ is zero then?

Comment: I'm not sure what $p_{r_0}$ is. The impulse in radial direction is a function $p_r(t)$, the impulse along the circle is $p_\theta$ or similar. The subscript is just a name, not a parameter. For the solution with $r(t)=r_0$ and thus $\dot r(t)=0$ you get also $p_r(t)=0$.